# angularjs data binding with button not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make the same functionality with the google form, which is when user choose different question type, it will show different style for data input, such as text, paragraph text, multi-choice.

**Here is the link of my** [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/d3OZVve9P4kagK82Cnrh):

My problem is when I choose one of the question type, it does not work, goes back to the last state.

I don't know why.

Here is part of my code:

```
<tr>
    <th>
        <label class="question_label">Question Type</label>
    </th>
    <td>
        <select class="question_dropdown" ng-model="question.type">
            <option value= "text">Text</option>
            <option value= "paragraph">Paragraph Text</option>
        <option value= "radio">Multiple Choice</option>
        <option value= "checkbox">Checkboxes</option>
        <option value= "list">Choose from a list</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
<div class="question_typeContainer" ng-switch="question.type">
    <div class="question_typeText" ng-switch-when="text">
    <input class="question_textfield disabled" value="Their answer" disabled>
</div>
    <div class="question_typeText" ng-switch-when="paragraph">
    <input class="question_textfield disabled" value="Their answer" disabled>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the extra key in each element of item, it works. Is there any other nice method?

Comment: Read about scope isolation.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine if you use ng-show instead of ng-switch-when. Try this out.

```
<div class="question_typeContainer">
  <div class="question_typeText" ng-show="question.type == 'text'">
    <input class="question_textfield disabled" value="Their answer" disabled>
  </div>
  <div class="question_typeText" ng-show="question.type == 'paragraph'">
    <input class="question_textfield disabled" value="Their answer" disabled>
  </div>
</div>
```